# Wordpress how to use get_post_format_link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to use the get_post_format_link and can't figure out how to use it. I want to be able to click a link from the homepage that will tell the category.php to only show video posts when I land on it. I have the following code in my functions.php

```
function get_post_format_link( $format ) {
$term = get_term_by('slug', 'post-format-' . $format, 'post_format' );
if ( ! $term || is_wp_error( $term ) )
    return false;
return get_term_link( $term );
}
```

I just want to figure out how to physically code the link, so for example:

```
<a href="post-format-video">more videos</a>
```

But that doesn't work! Would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: You more likely have a configuration problem with a software product here. Please contact the vendor for your support options, Stackoverflow is not the Wordpress support forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while permalinks are on, the url format is:

```
/type/{post format}/
```

for more, see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39925/does-wordpress-generate-an-automatic-page-for-post-formats

Comment: Thanks Marzab. That's my problem, I didn't have permalinks on! Thanks again.